# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a tag for the "Scout" programming language?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't know what *Scout* is, but here's the story, I dual booted my Windows XP last week, installing Linux Mint 12 and I wanted today to download Eclipse IDE.

On the download page, I see [this](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-scout-developers/indigosr1)

`Developing Scout applications is supported by this Scout Developers Package.`

I googled "scout" and found [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167819107001019) and [this](http://gpgpu.org/static/vis2005/PDFs/E.ScoutIntroduction.pdf) and more of course...

Anyway, the question is, if Scout is not a popular language then why would Eclipse make an IDE for it?

If it is popular, then why doesn't Stack Overflow have a tag for it?

If you search for `scout` in the tag list, you'll see `bugzscout` which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: I don't really care about scout...Just asking :)

Comment: Are there questions that should be tagged thus?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta maybe if you create the tag, there will be questions tagged with it, but as long as people don't find the tag, they will never tag their questions with it,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the time this answer was written there were zero questions that [mention Eclipse Scout](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Beclipse+%2Bscout+is%3Aquestion&submit=search).

In order for a tag to exist, it has to be attached to one or more questions.

Comment: fine I'll learn scout and ask a question about it tomorrow :) just kidding lol :D

Comment: Better, ask *two* questions *and* create a decent tag wiki so that New Tag Deletionists such as myself aren't tempted to nuke it.

Comment: No longer true, clicking on the link above leads to two questions :-)

Comment: Welp, let's see if the trend continues.

Answer (score 12):

At Eclipse, Scout isn't a programming language as mentioned in your references, but an Eclipse based framework to build business apps. So, the language behind Eclipse Scout is Java.

As questions will arise on Stack Overflow, I would like to suggest using [eclipse-scout](/questions/tagged/eclipse-scout) as a tag to avoid confusion with the many other uses for the word 'scout' (i.e. google for 'eclipse scout' will return meaningful hits)

Answer (score 7):

Tags are created by the community as needed.  When someone asks a question about scout and tags it with scout, the tag will be created.

Answer (score 4):

Because we don't keep tags for things that aren't being used.  Think about it this way: how useful would tags be as a way to organize questions if we created one for every tech-related term you could think of?  There are already somewhere around 31,000 tags in existence on SO.  Do you really *want* more?

Of course, if you ask some questions about Scout, then by all means create it.